# SQL query to access a field collection's data? At them moment, I'm only getting field_collection_item returned

Tags: entities, database

In the below example, I am trying to return the value of a field from all the field collections in the database but only get *field_collection_item*. This example is just the most basic field collection sql possible.

```
SELECT field_collection_item.item_id AS item_id, 'field_collection_item' AS field_data_field_grade_decimal_field_collection_item_entity_
FROM 
field_collection_item field_collection_item
```

What do I need to change in this example? My SQL is terrible unfortunately. I just can't return any values from field collections using sql. I need to be able to do this for Forena Reports.
I'm getting the above code from views which returns the field collection values.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is return field values from a field collection using sql. The above code doesn't return the ID of the field collection; it returns a decimal field in the field collection when used in views.

Comment: Notice that you don't need `'field_collection_item' AS field_data_field_grade_decimal_field_collection_item_entity_` and `FROM 
field_collection_item field_collection_item` can simply be `FROM 
field_collection_item`.

Comment: But I need to return the value of *the field_data_field_grade_decimal_* fields. Views does it with the above output but it doesn't work if I query the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the field_collection_field_get_entity() function to obtain the desired result without writing SQL, like this:

`$node = node_load(12);
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_fc_field');
foreach ($items as $item) {
$fc = field_collection_field_get_entity($item);
// Do something with $fc
dpm($fc);
}`

Comment: It's for Forena reports so I need it as SQL unfortunately.

Comment: You simply need the field collection item id associated with the node and then you have to make inner join with the tables containing the values. I will post a sample code here later tonight.

Comment: Thanks, but could you wait until tomorrow. I want to put my final code query in the question as I feel that I won't be able to do it myself. I'm going to put a bounty on it as well.